# Are exclusive taxonomy terms possible?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, content-restriction

I'm creating a site that requires users' content to be exclusive to the user. Ideally I would like this to extend to taxonomy terms.

Example:

- I have a taxonomy "Clients"
- UserA creates the term "My Client"
- UserB creates the term "My Client"

Is it possible to

1. Make sure that both entries for "My Client" exist separately?
2. Make sure that each user can only choose their own version of "My Client" to apply to posts?
3. Make sure that, before UserB creates "My Client", UserA's version is invisible to UserB?

Comment: This is quite interesting, but I doubt anyone would have ready-made answer. You could try implementing it and share what issues there are.

Answer (score 0):

with enough effort almost anything is possible, but it might not be easy.

what you basically want is for each user to have its own taxonomy, but merge them all when displaying it on the front end. The easiest path is probably to go multisite with a site per author and aggregate things on the front end.